# Python: Program is only multiplying the last number the user inputs rather than all of them

Tags: python, list

This is my first time posting. Please bare with me.
I have been working on this program for about a month and I cannot get it to run properly. When the user runs the program, you will be asked to input the hours worked by four employees. The program will then multiply the hours worked for each employee and print their gross pay for each of them. The problem is, it is only multiplying the last number I input and prints that as the gross pay for all four employees. I could really use some help.

If you need more information or want me to clarify anything, please let me know. All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Start:

```
NUM_EMPLOYEES = 4 

employeehours = [ ] 

for i in range (NUM_EMPLOYEES):

    print('Enter the hours worked by employee ', i + 1, ':', sep = '', end = ' ')
    employeehours = float(input())

pay_rate = 14

for i in range (NUM_EMPLOYEES):
   
    gross_pay = employeehours * pay_rate 
    print('Gross pay for employee', i + 1, ': $', format(gross_pay , '.2f'), sep = ' ')
```

Comment: You overwrite your variable `employeehours` in your loop with a single float instead of adding the float to your list. Afterwards it only contains one number. You need to store all inputs in a list. For the outputs you need to loop over your list of inputs and multiply the individual hours with the pay per hour. Not four time the last inputted value as you do now.

Comment: Please learn how to code via tutorials (start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)  instead of taking weeks to solve problems you are ill equipped to handle with your current level of knowledge. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), take the [tour] read through [ask] and take [mre] to heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are setting `employeehours` to last floating value.  your code is right almost.

```
NUM_EMPLOYEES = 4 

employeehours = [ ] 

for i in range (NUM_EMPLOYEES):

    print('Enter the hours worked by employee ', i + 1, ':', sep = '', end = ' ')
    employeehours.append(float(input()))

pay_rate = 14

for i in range (NUM_EMPLOYEES):
   
    gross_pay = employeehours[i] * pay_rate 
    print('Gross pay for employee', i + 1, ': $', format(gross_pay , '.2f'), sep = ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

So it should look like this:

```
NUM_EMPLOYEES = 4
PAY_RATE = 14
employee_payment = []

for i in range(NUM_EMPLOYEES):
    hours = float(input(f'Enter the hours worked by employee {i+1}: '))
    employee_payment.append(hours * PAY_RATE)

for i in range(NUM_EMPLOYEES):
    print(f'Gross pay for employee {i}: {employee_payment[i]}')
```

At the beginning you defined a list, and then you are assigning the value to the same variable, thats why the output is only one employee payment